# How can I establish a very stable connection between my host computer and Jetson NX Devkit?

Tags: ip, real-time, ros, slam, jetson-xavier

I am working on a RC car project. Currently, the issue that I am facing is network related. I am trying to map and localize myself on the third floor of an old building. At the same time, I would like to visualize this process in real-time.

Any advice on how I can sustain a very stable connection between my two devices? To clarify, I've been bringing my laptop with me and following the car that's driving.

When I used my school's network to establish the wireless connection, my connection freezes at certain spots. I am suspecting that although the same network, from one place to another things seem to be changing. OK, and then IP address is dynamic too.

I tried Jetson NX's Wi-Fi hotspot, which didn't perform well either. It was extremely slow. NX got frozen and the car didn't drive. There was a noticeable latency in the command I was sending and the car's behavior. And I also have a power concern too since the Jetson is run on a 5,000 MAh LiPo battery.

Finally, I tried my mobile hotspot, which is okay but not perfect. It tends to kick out the hotspot users from time to time.

EDIT: Just to give an idea of total area I measured it through Google maps to be approximately 24,819.20 ft² (2,305.78 m²). The floor consists of lots of walls.

Comment: Since I am working on ROS2, I used RMW Implementation :Cyclone DDS to establish this connection by supplying the IP addresses of each device.

Comment: I am surprised that NX hotspot solution did not work. I'd suggest you try it again and try to pinpoint why it is slow - for it is supposed to be the most stable option in your case. Anyway, do not expect any real-time from WiFi, it is not fit for this purpose. Build your system around an unpredictable latency expectation. If you want a real-time wireless channel - use one of the sub-GHz options. They'll be slow (in bandwidth) but allow a very decent latency.

Comment: @SK-logic thanks for the feedback, I just ordered an antenna for a better signal. Let's see if that makes it better. And I agree, using the built-in hotspot would make the most sense to maintain stable connection. I am also planning to do some sort of time profiling to learn exactly what might be going wrong. I downloaded a package that would let me choose a specific GHz, so I switched to 2.4 GHz from 5 GHz. It performed a lot better.